# How to override cy.request() and set up bearer authorization header globally?

Tags: cypress

I need to set the authorization bearer header for `cy.request()` globally to avoid setting it up multiple times.

[Here](https://lightrun.com/answers/cypress-io-cypress-default-headers-for-cyrequest-command#:%7E:text=As%20a%20workaround%20I%20overwrite%20cy.request%20method%20with%20my%20custom%20command%3A) I found some potential way to do it.

So in my `support/commands.ts` I have:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('request', (originalFn, ...options) => {
    const optionsObject = options[0];
    if (optionsObject === Object(optionsObject)) {
      optionsObject.headers = {
        authorization: `Bearer ${Cypress.env('authorizationToken')}`,
        ...optionsObject.headers,
      };
      return originalFn(optionsObject);
    }
    return originalFn(...options);
});
```

And in the test I have:

```
cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/someEndpoint',
    body: someBody
}).then(response => {
    expect(response.status).eq(200);
    return response.body;
});
```

And unfortunately, I get 401: Unauthorized error and it looks like the authorization bearer token was not added to headers:

[image]

What do I do wrong here? I use Cypress v 10.10.0

Comment: Did you check if optionsObject === Object(optionsObject) ever resolves to true? I guess it does not...

Comment: Other than that I would not use overwrite. I would add a command, which can receive type, url and body as argument, and returns cy.request with the arguments applied and the auth header.